# My iPhone App won't run with letterboxes in the new iPhone 5 simulator. How do I get it to letterbox?

Tags: ios, xcode4.5, iphone-5

I just downloaded the new version of Xcode and ran the app I've been developing.  For some reason, it didn't letterbox it.  I want to add in the letterboxing effect until I get the app ready for the new screen.

Thanks!

Comment: Delete the Default-568h@2x.png.

Comment: I've tried this, and it doesn't work.

Comment: Try a clean and build. The only thing that tells the OS how to display an app is the existence of that file.

Comment: I've done this...have you confirmed that this works for your own app?  It's not working here...I've deleted Default-568h@2x.png and clean/build.

Comment: Working fine for me. Have you tried deleting it from the sim and installing again?

Comment: `Reset Simulator` & `CLEAN` Project. `Build` again!

Comment: @Hemang Had the same problem, I believe yours is the real answer. Can you convert it from comment to answer form?

Answer (score 10):

*All glory to [@Hemang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1603234/hemang), this answer is from his comment above, and I'll gladly delete this answer in deference to his.*

I had the exact problem. Needed to do both of:

1. Reset the Simulator: from the menu, iOS Simulator > Reset Content and Settings... .
2. Clean your Xcode project (⇧⌘K). Personally, I like to clean the entire† derived data directory (⌥⇧⌘K).

† AKA ["nuke the entire site from orbit..."](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aCbfMkh940Q).

Comment: This didn't actually work for me **until** I blew away the whole DerivedData subdirectory (`MyAppName-ffyjuxtmnhzgrpenpsrlzelrqgtj/`).  Thanks for that suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

In the simulator, remove your development app. This will remove any leftovers. Now run again, without the new launch image.

Answer (score 3):

I think the easiest and quickest way to switch to letter boxed is simply to:

- remove the app from the device
- Uncheck the Default-568h@2x.png Target Dependency in the File Inspector tab
- Clean & Rebuild the app

If you want to switch back to the full 4inch form factor there's no need to delete the app again, just recheck the Target Dependency box for Default-568h@2x.png.

It's only when switching back to letter boxed that you have to remove the app from the device, because when you simply remove the target and not the app, the Default-568h@2x.png file remains on the device.

I'm building on the device, rather than the simulator, so in my opinion this would be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I added the Default-568h@2x.png image to see how my app would look.  It looked terrible. So I deleted the file and the app was no longer letterboxed.

To fix it, reset your simulator (note, you'll lose anything else on the simulator)

[image: Reset the simulator]

Then in XCode, `Clean`, then `Build`

[image]

Comment: No need to clean the entire simulator. Just remove your own app.

Comment: I guess you could.  This solves the problem though does it not? Thanks for the down vote!

Comment: Dear @LeoNatan , down votes are meant for bad answers. Not for answers that you don't like! Take a chill pill dude!

Answer (score -1):

On you simulator, go to

Hardware --> Device --> iPhone (Retina 4-inch)

That should show your app with the letter box

Comment: And if you read the comments, you'll notice he is already running the simulator, but because there was an image in the past, it is a leftover in the 4-inch simulator.

Comment: Agreed. But, the first sentence in the OP means the hardware on the simulator wasn't changed!